# When a sprint review should be held?

Tags: scrum

Generally a sprint is 2-4 weeks longer. A sprint review meting is required, but I went to know  - which time We will arrange Sprint Review ; at the end of a sprint ? or , in the middle of a sprint ?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

The Sprint Review is performed every time a Sprint ends, during this meeting the team analyzes what went right and wrong during the Sprint with a view to the next Sprint is carried in a better way. But during the Sprint you can not make a review that is still not over.

Comment: Well it's not quite right. It is true that review should happen at the end of the sprint, but it's not to look at what went wrong or good. Generally it is a time where the scrum team (product owner, dev team) meets with stakeholders, business people and presents the product. The meeting where you look at the process improvements is called the retrospective and involves the scrum team without the business people.